# How to transform sub-elements inside a column to data frame to rows using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I data frame like below

**Input**

```
 Cntr    Rate     Kg      Market      Sections  Dest
  Pkg   Per shp      0.5    WW        S1,S2       AF
  Pkg   Per shp      0.5    TB        S1,S2,S3    GB
  Pkg   Per shp      0.5    XS        S1          SG
  Pkg   Per shp      0.5    WW        ALL         US
  Pkg   Per shp      0.5    WW        S1,S2       FR
```

I  want to transform the dataframe to below format.

ALL in sections column should replaced by the max value here its (S1,S2,S3) and then separate rows for these should be created.

**Output**

```
Cntr    Rate     Kg Market    Sections  Dest
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 WW         S1       AF
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 WW         S2       AF
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 TB         S1       GB
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 TB         S2       GB
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 TB         S3       GB
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 XS         S1       SG
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 WW         S1       US
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 WW         S2       US
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 WW         S3       US
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 WW         S1       FR
Pkg   Per shp   0.5 WW         S2       FR
```

How can this be created in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `replace` then `split` and `explode`

```
df=df.assign(Sections=df.Sections.replace({'ALL':'S1,S2,S3'}).str.split(',')).explode('Sections')

 Cntr    Rate   Kg Market Sections Dest
0  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     WW       S1   AF
0  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     WW       S2   AF
1  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     TB       S1   GB
1  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     TB       S2   GB
1  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     TB       S3   GB
2  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     XS       S1   SG
3  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     WW       S1   US
3  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     WW       S2   US
3  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     WW       S3   US
4  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     WW       S1   FR
4  Pkg  Pershp  0.5     WW       S2   FR
```

Comment: Hey is there way we can automatically find the largest string value inside `Sections` column rather than hard cording the value to replace.

Comment: @aeapen `df.assign(Sections=df.Sections.replace({'ALL':df.loc[df.Sections.str.split(',').str.len().idxmax(),'Sections']}).str.split(',')).explode('Sections')
`